# Store Serialized Objects into Oracle DB (Preferably XML) C#

Tags: c#, oracle, xml-serialization, odp.net

Before I start writing code to handle this I want a feedback about what is the best way to go.

The background behind this problem is that I want to create some sort of storage for a C# object just in case the program crashes and the data is lost.

I want to store a *SERIALIZED* object into the database and then be able to query it from ODP.NET w/ successfully deserializing it and casting it into the same object.

By the way, the data for the serialized object would be around **50 MEGABYTES** after serialization.

**Usage:**
For every day there will be a serialized object stored, and be retrieved up to 10 times per day.

My questions are, if anyone has done this before;

- What is the best data type to use to store it? (I was thinking of serializing into flat XML and storing it as a CLOB/BLOB string)
- What is the fastest method for it, or are there any steps I need to be aware of to make it efficient?
- If I use the C# Serialize and Deserialize, am I guaranteed that the object will be the same (pretty much asking how reliable XML serialize is in C#, I was contemplating using JSon instead)

Let me know what you guys think!

Thanks!

Comment: How many of these things are you expecting to store? And are you expecting to read/write these records often? 50MB for a single record can seriously affect your database performance if it's overused.

Comment: every day there will be a serialized object stored (so like 1 a day), but it will be queried at least 3 times a day

Comment: BTW, sorry, I must have skipped right over the part in your question where you said that you'd create one per day...my bad.

Comment: no worries, it will actually increase from 1 per day to 30 per day in a bit haha so if you can advise me on what to do then it would be great too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object is mostly text, after you serialize the data (XML or JSON would be fine, assuming all of the properties truly are serializable), I'd recommend compressing your data into a byte array and storing it as binary. When you retrieve it, you'd just decompress it and then deserialize it. Text zips down very nicely, especially XML, so you might get that 50MB down to 10MB or less.

Based on your comment, zipping would absolutely be worthwhile. And if you're only adding 10MB or so per day, it sounds like it wouldn't negatively affect your database - just a few GB per year.

Comment: for now i only have 1 product, which means one entry per day... in a month we will have about 30 products, means 30 entries per day; would you still recommend the same thing?

Comment: If you're set on using the database, just be aware of the size increase. Crunch the numbers (try various compression approaches like gzip/zip/7zip and see how many bytes you'll actually be adding to the DB every day at your peak). Consider your database backup routines and storage, restore times for disaster recovery, and possible archiving strategies to help clear out old unneeded records. Definitely not a simple answer.

Comment: Personally, I'm not a big fan of storing big blobs in the database, just so I don't have to think about all these things. Instead, you can store them in the filesystem where your app server has read/write access, and just store filenames in the database that link them up. Then your database solution is simple and won't grow massively, so all you have to worry about is disk space for your files, which is cheap and easy to expand.

Comment: thanks, ill probably create a service to back up anything 7 days old and remove the row for that date

Comment: Agree with Joe's answer/comments, particularly storing these in the file system, which was designed for it.  It seems like there have been all kinds of moves toward making media servers out of relational databases over the years, and people seem to keep coming back to the file system (for a reason).  If they're just files, you could store them uncompressed, and enable native file system compression to save storage space if you need to.  That way the objects are easily viewable without extra work to decompress and unencode them.  Also, I'd store relative paths in the Db, not absolute paths.